# What is the custom url scheme for Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: ios, adobe

I'd like to open Adobe Acrobat from my App by using

```
 UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "xxxxx://")!)
```

Do you know its custom url scheme ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found it :

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "com.adobe.adobe-reader://")!)
```